# How can I write this Java arrow function in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new using Kotlin and I have to develop an app for Android Auto. I just did write a code for creating the first Hello World screen but now I wanna add a button for navigate to another screen. The problem is that I did this in Java like the code below but I don't know how to write this arrow function (`setOnClickListener(() -> getScreenManager().push(new SecondScreen(getCarContext())))`) in Kontlin

This is the code in Java:

```
public Template onGetTemplate() {
        //Row row = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Hello world").addText("Example").build();
        MessageTemplate template = new MessageTemplate.Builder("Hello world!").setTitle("Hello")
                .addAction(
                        new Action.Builder()
                                .setTitle("Next screen")
                                .setOnClickListener(
                                        () -> getScreenManager().push(new SecondScreen(getCarContext())))
                                .build())
                .build();
        return template;
    }
```

I have tried with this:
**1)**

```
MessageTemplate.Builder("Hello world!").setTitle("Hello")
            .addAction(
                Action.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Next screen")
                    .setOnClickListener(
                        () -> getScreenManager().push(SecondScreen(getCarContext()))).build()).build()
```

And this:
**2)**

```
MessageTemplate.Builder("Hello world!").setTitle("Hello")
            .addAction(
                Action.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Next screen")
                    .setOnClickListener(
                        {() -> getScreenManager().push(SecondScreen(getCarContext()))}).build()).build()
```

But I only received these results:

1. Expecting an expression
2. Expecting a name, Type mismatch: inferred type is (Any?) -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected, Expected no parameters

Comment: That's called a lambda function. Instructions here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Comment: Yeah, your second one should work if you remove the ``() ->``. The stuff before the arrow is where any variables passed into the lambda are declared, so that ``()`` is confusing it. It looks like the lambda you're providing takes some parameter, so it's interpreting it as an ``(Any?) -> Unit``" (a function that takes some object and returns "nothing") rather than the ``() -> Unit`` function (no parameters) that ``setOnClickListener`` is expecting

Comment: @cactustictacs yep it did, I also try with fun() = ... and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have tried this?

```
val template: MessageTemplate = Builder("Hello world!").setTitle("Hello")
            .addAction(
                Builder()
                    .setTitle("Next screen")
                    .setOnClickListener { getScreenManager().push(SecondScreen(getCarContext())) }
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
```

Comment: I finally use this 'cause it was the shortest way I found. Thanks!!